# Google Mobile Ads SDKS was initialized incorrectly

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm making a login activity that has a **Sign in with Google Button**

I am using a Firebase Auth to provide a Google sign-in method. I am following this documentation from [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?hl=en&authuser=0). I already follow along with the documentation, but my apps keep stoping. Why this problem occured? I've watched so many tutorials and searched for the same problem in Google. But I can't solve this problem. Here is my `LoginActivity` and the `activity_login.xml` code.

### Edit

After sawing the logcat, the Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. Here's the logcat

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzef.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.0.0:20)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@21.0.0:1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7488)
    ... 11 more
```

```kotlin
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var oneTapClient: SignInClient
    private lateinit var signInReq: BeginSignInRequest
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    private val REQ_ONE_TAP = 1 // Can be any integer unique to the Activity
    private var showOneTapUI = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        // [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        val googleSignInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, googleSignInOptions)
        // [END config_signin]

        // [START init_auth]
        // Initialize Firebase Auth
        auth = Firebase.auth
        // [END init_auth]

        oneTapClient = Identity.getSignInClient(this)
        oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInReq)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this) { result ->
                try {
                    startIntentSenderForResult(
                        result.pendingIntent.intentSender, REQ_ONE_TAP,
                        null, 0, 0, 0, null
                    )
                } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't start One Tap UI: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener(this) { e ->
                // No saved credentials found. Launch the One Tap sign-up flow, or
                // do nothing and continue presenting the signed-out UI
                Log.d(TAG, e.localizedMessage as String)
            }

        signInReq = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
            .setPasswordRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.PasswordRequestOptions.builder()
                .setSupported(true)
                .build())
            .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(
                BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                    .setSupported(true)
                    // Your server's client ID, not your android client ID
                    .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    // Only show accounts previously used to sign in
                    .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                    .build())
            .build()

        val googleButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnGoogleLogin)
        googleButton.setOnClickListener {
            // TODO: Implement Google Sign In

        }

        // [START click_textview]
        // Set the footer text view to be clickable
        val tvFooter: TextView = findViewById(R.id.txtFooterLogin)

        val foregroundColorSpan = ForegroundColorSpan(getColor(R.color.pickled_bluewood))
        val boldSpan = StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD)

        val spannableString = SpannableString(tvFooter.text.toString())
        val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
            override fun onClick(widget: View) {
                val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }

            override fun updateDrawState(drawState: TextPaint) {
                super.updateDrawState(drawState)
                drawState.isUnderlineText = true
            }
        }
        spannableString.setSpan(boldSpan, 23, spannableString.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        spannableString.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, 23, spannableString.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 23, spannableString.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        tvFooter.text = spannableString
        tvFooter.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
        // [END click_textview]
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        val currentUser = auth.currentUser
        updateUI(currentUser)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        when (requestCode) {
            REQ_ONE_TAP -> {
                try {
                    val googleCredential = oneTapClient.getSignInCredentialFromIntent(data)
                    val idToken = googleCredential.googleIdToken
                    // val username = googleCredential.id
                    val password = googleCredential.password
                    when {
                        idToken != null -> {
                            // Got an ID token from Google. Use it to authenticate
                            // with your backend
                            val firebaseCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
                            auth.signInWithCredential(firebaseCredential)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                                        val user = auth.currentUser
                                        updateUI(user)
                                    } else {
                                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                                        Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                                        updateUI(null)
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                        password != null -> {
                            // Got a saved username and password. Use them to authenticate
                            // with your backend
                            Log.d(TAG, "Got password")
                        }
                        else -> {
                            // Shouldn't happen
                            Log.d(TAG, "Not ID token or password!")
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    // Handle error
                    when (e.statusCode) {
                        CommonStatusCodes.CANCELED -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "One-tap dialog was closed.")
                            // Don't re-prompt the user
                            showOneTapUI = false
                        }
                        CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "One-tap encountered a network error.")
                            // Try again or just ignore
                        }
                        else -> {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't get credential from result: ${e.localizedMessage}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential: AuthCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser
                    updateUI(user)
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication Failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    updateUI(null)
                }
            }
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    private fun signOut() {
        // Firebase sign out
        auth.signOut()

        // Google sign out
        googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this) {
            updateUI(null)
        }
    }

    private fun updateUI(currentUser: FirebaseUser?) {
        if (currentUser != null) {
            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        // else {
        //     oneTapClient.beginSignIn(signInReq)
        //         .addOnSuccessListener { pendingIntent ->
        //             startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.intentSender, 1001, null, 0, 0, 0, null)
        //         }
        //         .addOnFailureListener { e ->
        //             // Handle error
        //         }
        // }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "GoogleActivity"
        private const val RC_SIGN_IN = 9001
    }
}
```

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors

Comment: I have submitted the edit. Please, kindly check my question again. Thank you _/|\_

Comment: Did you add the your App-Id in your app's `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: no I did not add App-id in my `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I cannot spot the issue at a first glance, but since you're using Kotlin, most like this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).